# While loop not checking or condition

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm doing c++ practice exercises. The one question that I'm on is as follows...

Write a program that continues to ask the user to enter any number other than 5 until the user enters the number 5.
Then tell the user "Hey! you weren't supposed to enter 5!" and exit the program.

★ Modify the program so that after 10 iterations if the user still hasn't entered 5 will tell the user "Wow, you're more patient then I am, you win." and exit.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int userNum;
    int numTimes = 0;

    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number: ";
        cin >> userNum;
        numTimes++;

    }while ((numTimes != 10) || (userNum != 5));
    {
        if (numTimes == 10)
        {
            cout << "Wow, you're more patient than I am, you win.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Hey! you weren't supposed to enter 5!\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get the or condition of the while loop to work.

Comment: `||` should be replaced with `&&`

Comment: Offtopic: your brackets after while-loop are **extremely** confusing. Don't write confusing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this in a confusing way, I would aim for expressiveness:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int userNum;
    int numTimes = 0;

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Please enter a number: ";
        std::cin >> userNum;

        if (userNum == 5) {
            std::cout << "Hey! you weren't supposed to enter 5!\n";
            break;
        }

        ++numTimes;

        if (numTimes == 10) {
            std::cout << "Wow, you're more patient than I am, you win.\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[`break`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break) allows you to conveniently exit a loop. Please don't "abuse" this to overcomplicate or to accomplish weird tricks, though. No one likes [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

Note how you [shouldn't `use namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Also try to use `++var` over `var++` as `var++` unnecessarily copies the object.

---

> ```
> Please enter a number: 5
> Hey! you weren't supposed to enter 5!
> ```

---

> ```
> Please enter a number: 12
> Please enter a number: 45
> Please enter a number: 12
> Please enter a number: 0
> Please enter a number: 9
> Please enter a number: 1
> Please enter a number: 2
> Please enter a number: 3
> Please enter a number: 4
> Please enter a number: 1
> Wow, you're more patient than I am, you win.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Change this here

```
while ((numTimes != 10) || (userNum != 5));
```

To this

```
while ((numTimes != 10) && (userNum != 5));
```

Because you want it to stop as soon as just one condition turns `false`. The way you have it now with `||`, it only stops if **both** conditions are true at the same time, so if the 10th number is `5`. It won't stop if just a `5` is entered, or if it just reached 10. It wouldn't even stop if a `5` is entered *after* 10 numbers.

Remember, `a || b` is `true` even if just one of `a` and `b` are true. But since the conditional is confusing this way, why not split the logic like this?

```
int main()
{
    int userNum;

    for (int numTimes = 0; numTimes < 10; numTimes++){
        std::cout << "Please enter a number: ";
        std::cin >> userNum;

        if (userNum == 5) {
            std::cout << "Hey! you weren't supposed to enter 5!\n";
            return 0;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Wow, you're more patient than I am, you win.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your condition. Your loop continues until the condition isnt met anymore.

```
while ((numTimes != 10) || (userNum != 5));
```

Forces the loop to continue until both conditions are false. If your numTimes == 10, then the userNum will be still < 5

```
while ((numTimes < 10) and (userNum != 5));
```

Is the correct condition